# Creating .deb for Go fails

Tags: dpkg, deb

Trying to build a custom package fails like this:

```
~/deploy# dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc 
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package deploy
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Foo Bar <admin@contoso.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build .
 debian/rules clean
dh clean --builddirectory=_build --buildsystem=golang --with=golang
   dh_auto_clean -O--builddirectory=_build -O--buildsystem=golang
   dh_autoreconf_clean -O--builddirectory=_build -O--buildsystem=golang
   dh_clean -O--builddirectory=_build -O--buildsystem=golang
 dpkg-source -b .
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../deploy_1.0.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b . subprocess returned exit status 255
```

Hereunder my ˋdebian/controlˋ  content.

```
Source: deploy
Maintainer: Foo Bar (admin@contoso.com)
Standards-Version: 4.6.1
Section: utils
Priority: optional
Homepage: https://gitlab.co toso.com/contoso/deploy
Rules-Requires-Root: no
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 12),
               debhelper (>=12),
               dh-golang,
               golang-any

Package: deploy
Architecture: amd64
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: Command used to send Docker webhooks.
 Command used to send Docker webhooks.
```

My ˋdebian/rulesˋ file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#export DH_GOLANG_EXCLUDES := internal
%:
        dh $@ --builddirectory=_build --buildsystem=golang --with=golang
```

And endly my repo structure :

```
# ls -la
total 39
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   6 Feb 17 00:23 .
drwx------ 9 root root  18 Feb 17 00:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   7 Feb 17 00:46 debian
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  10 Feb 16 22:41 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 841 Feb 16 23:52 main.go
```

Any hint on why it crashes because of a missing tarball?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, needed to change my rules file to the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@ --buildsystem=golang --with=golang

override_dh_auto_build:
        go build -v ./...

override_dh_auto_install:
        mkdir -p debian/deploy/usr/bin
        install deploy debian/deploy/usr/bin

override_dh_auto_test:
        echo "Skpping dh_auto_test"
```